# Expandable List Item Layout

Tags: android, xamarin, mobile, xamarin.android, expandablelistview

I am aware of the ExpandableListView, but as long as I can see the ExpandableListView has a list of items as child items.
What I want to do is have a list with parent items, and when I click on a parent item, it expands and shows more information.

*Note*: The layout that is shown when the parent item expands is not a list. It's just a simple layout, and since in every example I have seen the ExpandableListView is used with List as child items, I'm not sure if it is the correct control to be used in this situation.

*Possible solution*: I can use the ExpandableListView and have only one child item in the list, but I'm looking for something more elegant than to have a list with only one item in it.

Is the ExpandableListView the correct control to be used here?

**EDIT**: I'm using Xamarin Native (Xamarin.Android), not Xamarin.Forms

[image: Expandable View]

Answer (score 0):

I won't recommend using expandable ListView because it may cause performance issue when there are more data.

But if you want to implement it follow below steps:

1. Your model should be like List within List

   `public class Model1`
    {
       `public string Name { get; set; }
       public List<Model2> Model2Name { get; set; }`
    }
   `public class Model2
   {
       public string Name1 { get; set; }
   }`

   enter code here

Then your XAML should be like

```
<ListView
HasUnevenRows="True"
ItemSelected="ItemSelected"
ItemsSource="{Binding DataList}">
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
<DataTemplate>
<ViewCell>
<Grid >
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
<RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
<RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
<ColumnDefinition Width="9*"/>
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
<Label Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding Name}" YAlign="Center"/>
<ListView  Grid.Row="1"
IsVisible="{Binding ListVisibility}"
SeparatorVisibility="None"
ItemSelected="ProductSelected"
HeightRequest="220"
BackgroundColor="#f2f2f2"
HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
ItemsSource="{Binding Model.Products}">
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
<DataTemplate>
<ViewCell>
<Grid >
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
<RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
<RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
<Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"  Text="{Binding Name}"
YAlign="Center" />
</Grid>
</ViewCell>
</DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
</Grid>
</ViewCell>
</DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Now you have to wrap you model. for that you have to write a wrapper class as follow:

```
public class WrapperModel<T> : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public T Model { get; set; }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };
    bool listVisibility = false;
    public bool ListVisibility
    {
        get
        {
            return listVisibility;
        }
        set
        {
            if (listVisibility != value)
            {
                listVisibility = value;
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("ListVisibility"));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now in viewModel, you have to declare your List property as follows:

```
private List<WrapperModel<ProductCategoryModel>> dataList;
    public List<WrapperModel<ProductCategoryModel>> DataList
    {
        get { return dataList; }
        set
        {
            dataList = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("DataList");
        }
    }
```

Now initialize your list as follows:

```
 foreach (var item in List)
 {
 DataList.Add(new WrapperModel<ModelName>
 { Model = item, ListVisibility = false});
                        }
```

Now the list will be in collapsed state. To get the inner list on clicking each item , you have to set ItemSelected as follows:

```
private void ItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.SelectedItem == null) return;

        var tappedItem = (WrapperModel<ModelName>)e.SelectedItem;
        tappedItem.ListVisibility = !tappedItem.ListVisibility;
        ((ListView)sender).SelectedItem = null;
    }
```

If you have doubts, please let me know